# How to find a MoveTo destination filled by database?

Tags: database, search, collections, anylogic, population

I could need some help with a Anylogic Model.

Model (short): Manufacturing scenario with orders move in a individual route. The workplaces (WP) are dynamical created by simulation start. Their names, quantity and other parameters are stored in a database (excel Import). Also the orders are created according to an import. The Agent population "order" has a collection *routing* which contains the Workplaces it has to stop in the specific order.

Target: I want a moveTo block in *main* which finds the next destination of the agent *order*. 
Problem and solution paths:

1. I set the destination Type to agent and in the Agent field I typed a function `agent.getDestination()`. This function is in *order* which returns the next entry of the collection `WP destinationName = routing.get(i)`. With this I get a Datatype error (while run not compiling). I quess it's because the database does not save the entrys as *WP* Type but only String.
   **Is there a possiblity to create a collection with agents from an Excel?**
2. After this I tried to use the same *getDestination* as String an so find via findFirst the WP matching the returned name and return it as WP. `WP targetWP = findFirst(wps, w->w.name == destinationName);` 
   Of corse wps (the population of Workplaces) couldn't be found.
   **How can I search the population?**
   Maybe with an Agentlink?

I think it is not that difficult but can't find an answer or a solution. As you can tell I'm a beginner... Hope the description is good an someone can help me or give me a hint :)
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a possiblity to create a collection with agents from an Excel?

Not directly using the collection's properties and, as you've seen, you can't have database (DB) column types which are agent types.<sup>1</sup>

But this is relatively simple to do directly via Java code (and you can use the **Insert Database Query** wizard to construct the skeleton code for you).

> After this I tried to use the same getDestination as String an so find via findFirst the WP matching the returned name and return it as WP

Yes, this is one approach. If your order details are in Excel/the database, they are presumably referring to workplaces via some String ID (which will be a parameter of the workplace agents you've created from a separate Excel worksheet/database table). You need to use the Java `equals` method to compare strings though, not `==` (which is for comparing numbers or whether two objects are the same object).

> I want a moveTo block in main which finds the next destination of the agent order

So the general overall solution is

- Create a population of `Workplace` agents (let's say called `workplaces` in Main) from the DB, each with a String parameter `id` or similar mapped from a DB column.
- Create a population of `Order` agents (let's say called `orders` in Main) from the DB and then, in their on-startup action, set up their collection of workplace IDs (type `ArrayList`, element class `String`; let's say called `workplaceIDsList`) *using data from another DB table*.
- `Order` probably also needs a working variable storing the next index in the list that it needs to go to (so let's say an `int` variable `nextWorkplaceIndex` which starts at 0).
- Write a function in Main called `getWorkplaceByID` that has a single `String` argument `id` and returns a `Workplace`. This gets the workplace from the population that matches the ID; a one-line way similar to yours is `findFirst(workplaces, w -> w.id.equals(id))`.
- The MoveTo block (which I presume is in Main) needs to move the `Order` to an agent defined by `getWorkplaceByID(agent.workplaceIDsList.get(nextWorkplaceIndex++))`. (The `++` bit increments the index *after* evaluating the expression so it is ready for the next workplace to go to.)

For populating the collection, you'd have two tables, something like the below (assuming using strings as IDs for workplaces and orders):

- `orders` table: columns for parameters of your orders (including some String `id` column) *other* than the workplace-list. (Create one `Order` agent per row.)
- `order_workplaces` table: columns `order_id`, `sequence_num` and `workplace_id` (so with multiple rows specifying the sequence of workplace IDs for an order ID).

In the **On startup** action of `Order`, set up the skeleton query code via the **Insert Database Query** wizard as below (where we want to loop through all rows for this order's ID and do something --- we'll change the skeleton code to add entries to the collection instead of just printing stuff via `traceln` like the skeleton code does).

[image: Insert Database Query setup]

Then we edit the skeleton code to look like the below. (Note we add an `orderBy` clause to the initial query so we ensure we get the rows in ascending sequence number order.)

```
List<Tuple> rows = selectFrom(order_workplaces)
    .where(order_workplaces.order_id.eq(id))
    .orderBy(order_workplaces.sequence_num.asc())
    .list();

for (Tuple row : rows) {
    workplaceIDsList.add(row.get(order_workplaces.workplace_id));
}
```

<sup>1</sup> The AnyLogic database is a normal relational database --- [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/) in fact --- and databases only understand their own specific data types like `VARCHAR`, with AnyLogic and the libraries it uses translating these to Java types like `String`. In the user interface, AnyLogic makes it *look like* you set the column types as `int`, `String`, etc. but these are really the Java types that the columns' contents will ultimately be translated into.

AnyLogic *does* support columns which have **option list** types (and the special `Code` type column for columns containing executable Java code) but these are special cases using special logic under the covers to translate the column data (which is ultimately still a string of characters) into the appropriate option list instance or (for `Code` columns) into compiled-on-the-fly-and-then-executed Java).

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow :) To create a Population via Excel Import you have to create a method and call Code like this. You also need an empty Population. 
`int n = excelFile.getLastRowNum(YOUR_SHEET_NAME);
for(int i = FIRST_ROW; i <= n; i++){ 
    String name = excelFile.getCellStringValue(YOUR_SHEET_NAME, i, 1);
    double SEC_PARAMETER_TO_READ= excelFile.getCellNumericValue(YOUR_SHEET_NAME, i, 2);
    WP workplace = add_wps(name, SEC_PARAMETER_TO_READ);
}`

Now if you want to get a workplace by name, you have to create a method similar to your try. 
Functionbody:
`WP workplaceToFind = wps.findFirst(w -> w.name.equals(destinationName));
if(workplaceToFind != null){
//do what ever you want
}`

Comment: This is the old way (pre AnyLogic 7.2) of accessing Excel directly. Nowadays, with the built-in AnyLogic database, it is normally always better/easier to import the Excel into the built-in database and then use queries on that (where many AnyLogic blocks include ways to visually configure properties to be read from the database, as well as ways to automatically create populations and agent type definitions from database structures/contents).